# I am Using AMD processor for android programming with eclipse but but keep having this broken Google download Icon

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, datadroid

I perceive it is as a result of the broken icon on my installed sdk that has prevented me from installing creating and completely programming any app using the computer. I will greatly appreciate help from anyone who has been faced with this before and has fixed or resolved the issue.
[Broken google api](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ex2tY.jpg)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Official support for Eclipse as a development environment finished a while ago in favour of Android Studio. I wouldn't expect it to support API 24.

Comment: Thanks for that but i don't know if you have ever encountered such a problem and how you think i could resolve it

Comment: @AlainNikongnenwi I was forced to migrate to Android Studio once support ended for an earlier API so never tried to make Eclipse work with that API.